# Updating innerHTML with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to refresh my time set in an innerHTML. I'm using setInterval, but the innerHTML is still static. It's only when I refresh manually that the current time is showing....  fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eu9qrawc/

```js
const d = new Date();
const time_date = document.querySelector('.time_date');
const days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
const day = days[d.getDay()];
const seconds = d.getSeconds();


setInterval(() => {
  function showtime() {
    time_date.innerHTML = day + ' ' + seconds
  }
  showtime();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="time_date"></div>
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: Also, why exactly are you creating a new method in the interval, just to invoke it?  Edit: Which actually looks like a syntax error on the method definition

Comment: what's  TimeAlreadyDefinedasConstant ?

Comment: Thank you for the input. I've updated the code and added a fiddle.

Comment: The fiddle seems to work alright to me. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I'm setting up a clock, it has seconds. But the seconds does not count. i.e not refreshing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put new Date, day and seconds inside the setinterval loop.

```js
var d = new Date();
const time_date = document.querySelector('.time_date');
const days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
var day = days[d.getDay()];
var seconds = d.getSeconds();


setInterval(() => {
  function showtime() {
  d = new Date();
 day = days[d.getDay()];
 seconds = d.getSeconds();
  
  
  
  
  
    time_date.innerHTML = day + ' ' + seconds
  }
  showtime();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="time_date"></div>
```

Comment: You don't have to pre-declare the `var`iables, they will be displayed only inside the timer, and there they're assigned to as well.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, it's working perfectly now.

Comment: @FZs why would you want to re declare variables in a loop?

Comment: @DCR Was this comment response to my answer or my comment on your answer?

Comment: your comment to my answer

Answer (score 3):

You've forgotten to refresh your variables, so they will always contain the same value. Try this instead:

```js
const time_date = document.querySelector('.time_date');
const days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];


setInterval(() => {
  const d = new Date();
  const day = days[d.getDay()];
  const seconds = d.getSeconds();
  function showtime() {
    time_date.innerHTML = day + ' ' + seconds
  }
  showtime();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="time_date"></div>
```

Now the variables are local to the interval callback and created separately for each time the function is called (namely, in every second).

If you're going to call the `showtime` function elsewhere as well, consider moving the declarations into it.

```js
const time_date = document.querySelector('.time_date');
const days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];


setInterval(() => {
  function showtime() {
    const d = new Date();
    const day = days[d.getDay()];
    const seconds = d.getSeconds();
    time_date.innerHTML = day + ' ' + seconds
  }
  showtime();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="time_date"></div>
```